# How to create a custom command for the terminal?

Tags: terminal, automator, websites

Every time I make a new webpage, I do the following commands in the terminal.

```
touch index.html
mkdir stylesheets
mkdir javascripts
mkdir images
mkdir sass
open index.html -a sublime\ text
```

I wish to automate this. like I wish I could type

```
init newProject
```

and all the above commands would execute on its own.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with various methods, here's the easiest one in my opinion:

Paste this line in your `~/.bash_profile`

```
function initProject { touch index.html && mkdir stylesheets && mkdir javascripts && mkdir images && mkdir sass && open index.html -a sublime\ text; };
```

Save it and execute `source ~/.bash_profile`

Right now you can type `initProject` to get what you want.